# Use Custom Patterns in ReSharper Code Quality Analysis in TFS build

Tags: tfs, resharper, tfsbuild, code-analysis

I use ReSharper 2017.2.2 on the development machine together with Visual Studio 2017.5.

I'm using TFS 2017 Update 3.

On the TFS server, Visual Studio 2017.4 and ReSharper CLT 2017.2.2 are installed.

I'm using TFS build.

My goal is to do code analysis when building a solution.

[image]
I use the Resharper Code Quality Analysis task. I can configure it using the sln.DotSettings file which is at the root of the solution.

Standard code checks ReSharper successfully work. I can also change the warning level as shown here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alanwales.resharper-code-analysis
[image]

For this I use `ReSharper -> Options | Code Inspection -> Custom patterns`.
[image]

This rule works well in Visual Studio. When I save this rule to sln.DotSettings, the following lines are added:

```
 <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/StructuralSearch/Pattern/=4E6B3830DEEA6148909C23CD21C96E28/@KeyIndexDefined">True</s:Boolean>
 <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/StructuralSearch/Pattern/=4E6B3830DEEA6148909C23CD21C96E28/LanguageName/@EntryValue">JAVA_SCRIPT</s:String>
 <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/StructuralSearch/Pattern/=4E6B3830DEEA6148909C23CD21C96E28/MatchCatchClauseWithoutExceptionFilter/@EntryValue">False</s:Boolean>
 <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/StructuralSearch/Pattern/=4E6B3830DEEA6148909C23CD21C96E28/SearchPattern/@EntryValue">debugger</s:String>
 <s:String x:Key="/Default/PatternsAndTemplates/StructuralSearch/Pattern/=4E6B3830DEEA6148909C23CD21C96E28/Severity/@EntryValue">ERROR</s:String></wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```

I in the JS code specially added lines with `debugger`. But I do not get a warning on my custom patterns.

Does Resharper Code Quality Analysis support in TFS use Custom patterns?

**UPDATE 1**: I checked the launch of the code analysis via the console with the command: `InspectCode.exe -o="C:\temp\Results.xml" --no-swea "C:\BuildAgent\Thompson\_work\23\s\***.sln"`

In the Results.xml file, I found the required line:

```
<Issue TypeId="StructuralSearch" Severity="ERROR" File="***.WebResources\WebResources\new_\js\forms\***.js" Offset="406-415" Line="13" Message="debugger" />
```

**UPDATE 2**: I looked at the script code `RunResharperCodeAnalysisTool.ps1`. In this file there are the following lines:

```
...
$severityLevels = @{"Hint" = 0; "Suggestion" = 1; "Warning" = 2; "Error" = 3}
...
foreach($issue in $issuesElements) {
    $severity = @($issuesTypesElements | Where-Object {$_.Attributes["Id"].Value -eq $issue.Attributes["TypeId"].Value})[0].Attributes["Severity"].Value

    $severityLevel = $severityLevels[$severity]

    if($severityLevel -ge $severityLevels[$failBuildLevelSelector]) {
        $item = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            'Severity' = $severity
            'Message' = $issue.Attributes["Message"].Value
            'File' = $issue.Attributes["File"].Value
            'Line' = $issue.Attributes["Line"].Value
        }

        $filteredElements.Add($item)
    }
}
```

The Results.xml file has the following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generated by JetBrains Inspect Code 2017.2.2 -->
<Report ToolsVersion="109.0.20171006.123742">
  <Information>
    <Solution>..\..\BuildAgent\Thompson\_work\23\s\***\***.sln</Solution>
    <InspectionScope>
      <Element>Solution</Element>
    </InspectionScope>
  </Information>
  <IssueTypes>   
    <IssueType Id="StructuralSearch" Category="Structural Search Highlightings" CategoryId="StructuralSearch" Description="Structural Search Pattern" Severity="INVALID_SEVERITY" />    
    <IssueType Id="WebConfigErrors" Category="WebConfig Errors" CategoryId="WebConfigErrors" Description="" Severity="ERROR" />
  </IssueTypes>
  <Issues>
    <Project Name="***">
      <Issue TypeId="WebConfigErrors" File="***.WebResources\Web.config" Offset="531-650" Line="17" Message="Invalid module qualification: Failed to resolve assembly Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" />
      <Issue TypeId="WebConfigErrors" File="***.WebResources\Web.config" Offset="916-1035" Line="20" Message="Invalid module qualification: Failed to resolve assembly Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" />
      <Issue TypeId="StructuralSearch" Severity="ERROR" File="***.WebResources\WebResources\new_\js\forms\***.js" Offset="406-415" Line="13" Message="debugger" />
    </Project>
  </Issues>
</Report>
```

My Custom Patterns has `Severity="INVALID_SEVERITY"` which is not on the `$severityLevels` list.

Comment: Hi Kolya, any update on this, have you figured it out?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Hi. Your answer is helpful. I wanted to wait for the answer of the extension developer.

Comment: Any update on this? I didn't find any answer from the extension developer. What is your solution eventually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it works well with the command line, seems the issue is not related to TFS side, may more related with the 3-party task.

If this will not work with the [Resharper Code Quality Analysis](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alanwales.resharper-code-analysis) task, you could directly call the `InspectCode.exe`  command during the build task by use a command line task or customize extension. Then publish the result file to TFS.

Besides, as a workaround, you could also  be able to  return warnings and errors from your powershell script using [**logging commands**](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/573).  With using `task.logissue type=error` you could fail the build task and then fail the build.